# Initialization of array type (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization

According to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization, one of the effects of list initialization is:

> If T is an aggregate type, aggregate initialization is performed.

Since arrays are aggregate types, when I initialize an array `int array[3] = {1, 2};`,

I believe what happens is

1. List initialization
2. Aggregate initialization
3. Copy initialization where 1, 2 are copy initialized from the corresponding clause of the initializer list
4. Remaining values are value initialized  (zero initialization)

This makes sense to me as the values of the array will be 
 {1, 2, 0}.

However, as I continued reading I noticed another effect of list initialization which was:

> If T is an aggregate type and the initializer list has a single
>   element of the same or derived type (possibly cv-qualified), the
>   object is initialized from that element (by copy-initialization for
>   copy-list-initialization, or by direct-initialization for
>   direct-list-initialization).

So will declaring an array `int array[3] = {1};` where the "initializer list has a single element"  be a different process than when there is more than one element? (i.e. `int array [3] = {1, 2};`)? This doesn't make sense to me, but I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: `1` is not the same type as `int[3]` so that clause doesn't apply here. An example would be `S t;  S s = { t };` where `S` is an aggregate class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That effect won't be applied, as the quotes said,

> If T is an aggregate type and the initializer list has a single element of **the same or derived type (possibly cv-qualified)**, the object is initialized from that element (by copy-initialization for copy-list-initialization, or by direct-initialization for direct-list-initialization).

Given `int array[3] = {1};`, `{1}` has a single element `1` of type `int`, which is not a same or derived type of the array type `int[3]`.